# What are my options against an accountant who has botched an IRS audit?

Tags: taxes, refund, audit

About 8 months ago, I asked on this list what to do when I received a notice from the IRS that I was being audited but I only got the paperwork 2 weeks after the deadline to reply. I was advised to use an accountant which I did.

The firm I chose had years of experience. However, the tax expert they assigned to me forgot about my audit or to do a process a couple of times despite my correspondences with him. The case has gone to tax court, and then moved on to some other department of the IRS and I complained to the owner of the firm that this expert has been negligent in his duties. The owner agreed and assigned the audit over to another tax expert.

I have emails of my correspondences of the first tax expert and his apologies of forgetting when he did.

My question is, what recourse do I have once the finish the job? Or should I not wait that long?

Is one supposed to give the firm more time with the other tax expert?

FYI, I was supposed to get a refund this year but the IRS has said that it's using it towards the amount they are claiming against me. The amount is simple whatever I got as a refund in a previous year. I have the proof that I reported correctly, I am waiting for the second tax expert to show it to the IRS.

If they accept my proof that I filed accurately, will the IRS automatically send me a refund or do I need to follow a process for it?

Comment: Just to be clear, I am looking to see if people would do anything or if the general attitude is that people goof up, even professionals, so let it go and hope that they straighten it all out. That is also an answer. I just don't want to be a "sucker" if it is the case where they are charging a lot of money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you purchased the normal services and guarantees:

It's the tax accounting firm's job to make sure you pay exactly, and only, the appropriate amount of taxes based on the data you gave them. Any costs of correcting an error they made (including any penalty the IRS might charge for late filing) should be borne by them.

Yes, you would normally just wait for the accounting firm to straighten this out. After they have done so, you will need to decide whether you still trust them, trust them less after the mistake, or trust them more after seeing how they handled the mistake; at that time you can decide whether you want to use them again or take your business elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, what recourse do I have once the finish the job? Or should I not wait that long?

You should not wait to escalate this issue, as you have. You've been assigned a new associate, which will hopefully do better.

That said, if you can show that due to their negligence you got a worse outcome that you otherwise would have without it - you can demand damages from them. This is called "malpractice". Malpractice process starts once your case is adjudicated and complete and you can show the direct link between the negligence and the negative outcome.

Personal service providers like doctors, accountants, tax advisers, lawyers, etc - have professional liability insurance coverage for these cases and their insurance will work with you on resolution and potential settlement.

That said, in your case it sounds like the negligence didn't result in any negative outcome. You filed a Tax Court petition, and it was routed to the IRS appeals/settlement division to settle it, and if that fails you'll go back to the Tax Court. Other than wasted time, it doesn't sound like there was any particular damage? Maybe you can show that you could have avoided the tax court involvement had they not wasted time (i.e.: they missed the statutory 90 days deadline because of their negligence, and nothing else), and claim the associated costs, but other than that not much you can do for now.